# Calling contract method(0x..) using web3.py

Tags: web3.py, method

How to call the method like 0x0eb0d6a5 in web3.py? Seems like it is function name but is it different when calling function name?

Answer (score 2):

`0x0eb0d6a5` looks like a function selector. You can use [Contract.get_function_by_selector()](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.contract.html#web3.contract.Contract.get_function_by_selector) to fetch this function using the selector.